# Serialization attributes on TableEntity in Azure Table Storage

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, azure-table-storage

Im using web API to return data in azure table storage.  Im returning a class that I 'm inheriting TableEntity in a class and adding properties but want to keep to the .Net convention of capitalized property names but also keep to the JavaScript/json convention of lowercase properties names.

I've tried adding the Json.net property attributes to the class but it appears to be ignored. E.g.:

[JsonProperty("id")]
public string ID {get;set;}

If the instance has a value set on ID, null is represent in the serialized result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - while this doesn't answer the direct answer of how to get TableEntity to respect JSON.net attributes...   I was able to solve the use case by overriding the ReadEntity and WriteEntity method in the inherited class:

e.g.

```
public class User : TableEntity{
   //Upper case name
   public string Name {get; set};
   public override void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, AzureTableStorage.EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext){
       base.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);
       //lower case
       this.Name = properties["name"];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tested this issue on my side and found it works well on my side and Azure. Here is my detailed steps, you could refer to it.

**Create a controller named UserInfoController in the Web API application with the `Get` function like this:**

```
// GET: api/UserInfo
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> Get()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(<your-Storage-ConnectionString>);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("UserInfo");
    TableQuery<User> query = new TableQuery<User>()
        .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Grade Four"));
    var results =await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
    //Serialize the object to string by using the latest stable version of Newtonsoft.Json
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
    return jsonString;
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class User : TableEntity
{
    public User(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = rowKey;
    }
    public User() { }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

Deploy the Web API application to Azure, then you could find the following result by calling the function via Fiddler.

[image]

In summary, please try to check the version of Json.NET you are using. If you aren't using the latest (9.0.1), then please try to upgrade to the latest version and run your application again to find whether it could work as expected.

Comment: Well I guess I could change the return type to string but since other internal operations call the function directly if prefer to return it as the object, in your example rerun the user, to avoid the added overhead of deserilaization in those functions that call this.

Comment: Based on your comment, I changed the return type of `Get` function to `Task<IList<User>>`, then I could get the serialized result as expected. Also, you could make a global configuration about Json serialization by adding `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();` to your `WebApiConfig.Register()`, you could follow this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_camelcasing)  for a better understanding of it.

Comment: The problem is the serialization TO azure table storage via the SDK does not respect the JsonProperty("lowercase") attribute despite being serialized to go over the wire/odata.   So while i can get data from MY web api with the attributes respected (lowercase property names) the data in the azure table storage still follows the capitalized structure.

for example coming from a client throught my web api to the table storage via the SDK goes

propertyname (client serialized) --> (web api deserialzed) PropertyName --> (azure table serialized) PropertyName 

Just seems unexpected to IMO.